# Is it possible to reproduce the 429 error (Too many requests) locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I use bonsai.io server for elasticsearch.

I use chewy gems as well as the sidekiq strategy for sidekiq workers.

and very often I started to get about 429 (Too many requests)

Is it possible to reproduce this error locally in order to try to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can see what the logstash test suite does to mimic and test this behaviour [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/spec/integration/outputs/retry_spec.rb#L91)